# Xcode couldn't find NSObject's method - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I got into a weird situation, I am trying different methods of NSObject just to know how it works. I am currently testing them on a simple view based application on iOS. I created a random object greater which returns objects in id as basic NSObject, Than I want to determine what object it is by getting their class name. Therefore I used below method...

**Link Edited**

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/className

Now when I call this method on my random object, Like...

```
[object className];
```

Xcode gives me an error saying this...

> Instance method '-className' not found

Is this method deprecated? Or Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I clicked and all I got was an error with the URL [http://method name classname](http://method%20name%20classname).

Comment: sorry my bad, something went wrong while writing a question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For whatever reason, the `className` method only exists on Mac OS X. On iOS you can use `NSStringFromClass([object class])` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation it say's that it only available in Mac OS X.

```
className

Returns a string containing the name of the class.
- (NSString *)className
Return Value

A string containing the name of the class.
Discussion

This method is invoked by Cocoa’s scripting support classes.
Availability

    Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.
```

What is your purpose of finding class name.

Comment: Sorry I am noob, I am testing different methods and trying to get my self familiar with objective c. Thanks I will keep this in my mind